# Azure Data Explorer - clear table data before drop table?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/drop-table-command) for `.drop table` say that this only does a soft-delete of data. `.clear table data` on the other hand [does not mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/clear-table-data-command) this.

So I'm wondering, if I want to hard-delete / drop a table and its data, should I run `.clear table data` first and then only drop the table? Or will this result in the same as just running `.drop table`?

Answer (score 2):

`.clear table data` does the same as `.drop table`. If you need to force hard deletion of the data (e.g. for GDPR purposes), then you can look into purging an entire table - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/data-purge#purging-an-entire-table.

Comment: ok thanks. So except for purging, it is always soft-deleted?!